# Can I generate Bearer token programmatically with C# code?

Tags: c#, google-cloud-automl

I am using Google Cloud AutoML natural language. I am calling the RestAPI through C# code. It requires bearer token which currently I am generating through GCP (Google Cloud Platform) and use that in C# code but it expires after an hour.
So I wanted to generate this token through C# code so that I don't have to update every time my code with new token, which is being generating through GCP. I am sharing my code as an example. You can see currently token variable is assigned hard coded value.

```
            var client = new RestClient(@"https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/myproject-model/locations/us-central1/models/TCN6989xxxxxxxxx:predict\");
            string token = "ya29.c.Kl65B0pyEu5Kl2yO_ch0xhGwFuAbH1CvlUEjt5lBSmWW_dkzRIo8axxxxxxxzxzKEJ6jZEmMFdbVmtRJ2zFl45aDz-MqfHNDPFonUKvuk_opOFwtkRNEuCJ"; //for example
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            request.AddParameter("application/json", strPayload, ParameterType.RequestBody);

            response = client.Execute(request);
```

Any support will be appreciable.
Thanks
Amit

Comment: You'll have to make an http request to the identity provider.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate bearer token using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29208217/generate-bearer-token-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Nope, you won't be able to generate a bearer token yourself. You'll have to add some way of retreiving one to your code.

Comment: Thanks Josh for sharing the link. I have gone through this. This token is being used for Google APIs default model, it return Google themes. In my case I have created my own Project and model I have added specific themes and trained them. For that I have to create a Service account and add a key. So I need to create a token for that Service account/key so that it will return my model/themes which I have trained.